# Trying to simulate keyframing with geometry nodes to produce a repeating animation

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, keyframes, geometry

I am working on a project to show a vein being compressed, pinching off blood flow, and then decompressing. I am using Ryo Mizuta's procedural blood vessel project (https://youtu.be/whh1QblAGEo?si=BNpwC0YXT7EZY-43).

[image]

As you see in the screenshot, I was able to get the compression on the vein to work correctly but I have no idea how to animate it so it decompresses and recompresses.

This is my first venture into GeoNodes so I have no background knowledge to know where to begin. I did try to use the "scene time" node along with "switch" nodes to try to simulate the animation but I didn't get anywhere.

Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a Math Mix node after the Float curve output, expose its Factor input and keyframe it directly in the Geo Nodes modifier.

[image]